# How to use sox in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I downloaded and installed sox using the Mac OS X binary.

I am trying to run it using `sox` in the terminal but I keep getting command not found.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure its on your `PATH` if you are calling it as `sox`. If it's not you have 2 options:

1. Add the directory it was installed to to your `PATH`
2. Give a path to the `sox` binary as the call instead. For example (I used homebrew to install sox) my binary is at `/usr/local/bin/sox` so my command would start with that. If you'd like you can also use `alias` to shorten that.